# MATLAB: Split array

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a Matlab array

```
K=[2, 4, 5, 7, 7.3, 8, 9, 0, 2.1, 5, 7, 3] % 1x12
```

I need to split it into three arrays

```
[K1, K2, K3] = K
```

Where

```
K1= 1 x 2
K2= 1 x 4
K3= 1 x 6
```

Is there any single inline command doing such split?

```
[K1,K2,K3]=split(K,2,4,6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write one (I used `splitmat` to avoid overloading `split`):

```
function varargout = splitmat(K,varargin)
nextpos = 1;
for argnum = 1:nargin-1
    varargout{argnum} = K(nextpos:nextpos+varargin{argnum}-1);
    nextpos = nextpos + varargin{argnum};
end
```

Giving output:

```
>> [K1,K2,K3]=splitmat(K,2,4,6)
K1 =
     2     4
K2 =
    5.0000    7.0000    7.3000    8.0000
K3 =
    9.0000         0    2.1000    5.0000    7.0000    3.0000
```

Comment: If you want this kind of output `K1,K2,K3` rather than a single cell array, you can also do @Santhan's approach of `out = mat2cell(K,1,[2 4 6]);` and then `[K1,K2,K3]=out{:};`.

Answer (score 3):

This could be one better alternative as you don't need to create any separate functions nor do you have to split it manually like the other answers. It also has the advantage of creating only a single variable (a cell-array) instead of a list of variables.

Using [`mat2cell`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)

```
out = mat2cell(K,1,splitvec)
```

**Inputs:**

```
K = [2, 4, 5, 7, 7.3, 8, 9, 0, 2.1, 5, 7, 3];
splitvec = [2 4 6];
```

**Results:**

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

 2     4

out{2} =

5.0000    7.0000    7.3000    8.0000

out{3} =

9.0000         0    2.1000    5.0000    7.0000    3.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `deal`:

```
p1 = 2;
p2 = 4;
[K1, K2, K3] = deal(K(1:p1),K(p1+1:p1+p2),K(p1+p2+1:end))
```

Comment: I think you mean `[K1, K2, K3] = deal(K(1:p1),K(p1+1:p1+p2),K(p1+p2+1:end))`.

Comment: @Ramashalanka yes you're right. My mistake. Edited.